# Separating recessed lighting and Ceiling Fan

Tags: wiring

I have Recessed Lights and a Ceiling Fan with light (remote controlled no pull chains) on one single light switch. Usually, just unscrew the lighting so I can just control the fan. I wanted to split the devices. In same box my fireplace fan goes to a single switch as well. I planned to put lights on a signal and the fireplace fan and ceiling fan on a single pole double switch.

All grounds already together, all whites already together...Fan Black i ran to top of double pole switch, fireplace fan to lower part and ran one single hot to the double pole switch and did not break the tab.....fireplace fan worked but ceiling fan did not. I switched them, again, the fireplace fan worked and the ceiling fan did not.

I can't decide if i'm doing something wrong or if the Ceiling fan black needs cut back since it is old and was soldered with the hot in the original setup or if I blew the receiver in the fan possibly.

Thoughts on trouble shooting?

Comment: Can you post photos of the boxes involved?  Also, do you have an actual *double pole* switch or just a double switch? The tab has me concerned...

Comment: OP means "single pole double switch" as said end of paragraph 1, the other mentions of "double pole" are erroneous.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a double pole switch.

All you need to do is make a connection on the hot wire of the fireplace and the hot wire of the ceiling fan AFTER a single pole switch. So you feed the switch hot, and then join the switched hot to the hots of the two devices. Then whenever you flip that switch both devices will come on.

Good luck and stay safe!